# Invert the size in scatterplots in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following code

```
plot_S<-ggplot(Sdat, aes(x = Nadd, y = Sratio, size = Variance))+
      geom_point(aes(colour=Fert,shape = Fert))+
      scale_color_manual(values=c("#2b2b2b", "#838383")) +
      theme_bw()+
      geom_abline(intercept=-0.0107, slope=-0.0010, colour = "#838383", size = 1.0)+
      geom_abline(intercept=-0.2068, slope=-0.0010, colour="#2b2b2b", size=1.0)+
      labs(x=expression(Delta*"N addition"),y="ln S ratio")
plot_S
```

Which produces the following:

[image]

However i want the higher variance (=1.2) represented by smaller points and vice versa the lower variance values represented by larger points.
Any suggestion? (I want to keep Variance this way, without dividing it by 1)

Answer (score 4):

We can apply a transformation to the size scale.
Using a dummy dataset:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = depth, y = table, color = cut, size = price)) +
    geom_point()
```

[image]
^ Normal `scale_size`

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = depth, y = table, color = cut, size = price)) +
    geom_point() +
    scale_size(trans = 'reverse')
```

[image]
^ Transformed `scale_size`

Comment: Thanks, but still it doesn't seems to work properly in my case: you get large values only (similarly to your "Transformed `scale_size`")... I think because most of my datapoints have 'price' around 5000(?). Is there a way to have more than three sizes in ggplot2?

Comment: That would be easier if you can provide a sample of your data frame. Edit the question and put the result of `dput(Sdat)` in it (or just the head if it's too big)